# RavenDB 2.5 (2956) Nested IIS Web Application - URL conventions for HTTP API?

Tags: http, iis, curl, ravendb

I'd like to use the HTTP API to get things done with a RavenDB instance running as an IIS Web Application. The documentation on that page does not introduce the the conventions used for URLs. It jumps directly to making use of curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/docs/bobs_address without elaborating for the scenario where RavenDB is running as a Web Application. A representation of my specific setup is that Raven DB + its Silverlight Studio are located at http://localhost/my_site/raven_db/ -- RavenDB web app is the child of the website's web app.

I want to GET an existing document (person/alice) and to create a new one (person/bob), but can't figure out the URLs needed.

- http://localhost/my_site/raven_db/docs

  - GET = some housekeep data is returned, not particularly useful
- http://localhost/my_site/raven_db/docs/person/alice
- http://localhost/my_site/raven_db/docs/Person/alice (is RavenDB case sensitive?)

  - GET = Not Found
- http://localhost/my_site/raven_db/person/bob
- http://localhost/my_site/raven_db/Person/bob (is RavenDB case sensitive?)

  - GET = Not Found

What are the URLs needed in my use-case for the CURL operations? Is the name of the database needed anywhere (ex: "*MyDataBox*") so that RavenDB does not try to hit the "*system*" database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention turns out to be:

http://localhost/my_site/raven_db/databases/MyDataBox/docs/person/alice

- Plus, it is not case sensitive.

Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/qxlL45p78Xs